# How do I include a project dependency with a classifier

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a sub-project with a classifier, `test-fixtures`, that I want to include into an adjacent sub-project:

```
dependencies {
  implementation(project(":producer"))
}
```

I assumed that would be a trivial task, but I can't seem to find out how. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this was not a classifier in the maven sense. The variant (what gradle calls them) was created by the java-test-fixtures-plugin. See [user guide on testing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures).

It is used by importing the dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
  testFixtures(project(":producer"))
}
```

I had a little problem on this since this inhibits my freedom to select the configuration I needed in order to include this jar in an ear-file. I found a  way around this by adding it manually as the earlib(...)-method actually does:

```
dependencies {
  add("earlib", testFixtures(project(":producer")))
}
```